# How to use vector acsess element through function

Tags: visual-c++, vector

This code is made for the multiplication of two arrays given by the user

```
typedef vector<vector<int> > arr ;


void multiply (arr &arr1 ,arr &arr2 )
 {
arr res ;
  unsigned new_row = arr1.size() ;
unsigned new_col = arr2.at(0).size();
for(int i = 0 ; i < new_row ; i++)
  {
    vector <int> vec ;
    res.push_back(vec ) ;
    for(int j = 0 ; j<new_col ;j++)
    {
        int x = 0 ;
        res.at(i).push_back(x);
        for(unsigned k =0 ; k <arr2.size();k++)
        {
            res.at(i).at(j) +=           arr1.at(i).at(k)*arr2.at(k).at(j);
        }
        cout<< res.at(i).at(j) ;
   }
    }

  }    
  int main()
  {
unsigned rows_number1 = 0 , columns_number1 = 0 ;

arr arr1 ;

cout<<"MATRIX A "<<endl<<endl ;
cout << "The Rows : " ;
cin >> rows_number1 ;
cout << "The Columns :" ;
cin>> columns_number1 ;
for(int i = 0 ; i<rows_number1;i++)
{
    vector<int> newr ;
    arr1.push_back(newr);
    for(int j = 0; j<columns_number1 ;j++)
    {
        int x ;
        cout<<"The Member ("<<i+1<<","<<j+1 <<") :" ;
        cin>>x ;
        arr1.at(i).push_back(x);

    }
}
unsigned rows_number2 = 0 , columns_number2 = 0 ;

arr arr2 ;

cout<<"MATRIX B "<<endl<<endl ;
cout << "The Rows : " ;
cin >> rows_number2 ;
cout << "The Columns :" ;
cin>> columns_number2 ;
for(int i = 0 ; i<rows_number2;i++)
{
    vector<int> newr ;
    arr1.push_back(newr);
    for(int j = 0; j<columns_number2 ;j++)
    {
         int x ;
        cout<<"The Member ("<<i+1<<","<<j+1 <<") :" ;
        cin>>x ;
        arr1.at(i).push_back(x);

    }
}

system("cls");

if(columns_number1!=rows_number2)
{
    cout<<"Error Multiplication Dimensions" <<endl ;
}
else
{
    cout << "A * B ="<<endl;
    multiply(arr1,arr2);
 }
 }
```

why there is an error and what is the other way ??
how i can improve the code to multiplicate two arrays
Edited : i tried with two 2*2 arrays using console input and output and this is my full code
The problem is out_of_range exception but i don't  know why

Comment: What error is where?

Comment: It looks like this is performing matrix multiplication, which means that you must be passing an `a x N` and an `N x b` `arr` into the function, otherwise you'll get an out of range error. This code seems to work fine to me: [ideone](https://ideone.com/lOAUoa)

Comment: The problem is at the sentence      unsigned new_col = arr2.at(0).size();

Comment: Are you passing in an `arr2` that's not empty? Otherwise that'll be out of range...Can you [edit] your question to include the values you're passing to the function and the exact error you're getting?

Comment: I have tried with non empty    arr  but always an error

Comment: Can you post the vectors you tried with? Like I said in [my above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53548632/how-to-use-vector-acsess-element-through-function#comment93964016_53548632), I cannot reproduce your error with my own vectors.

Answer (score 0):

When you mulitply to matrices, there are strict constraints on the input.

1. The number of columns of the first matrix must be the same as the number of rows of the second matrix.
2. When your matrix is represented by a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, you'll have to make sure that ALL the nested `std::vector`s are of the same size.

Also, don't assume that `arr2` is non-empty. When it is empty, `arr2.at(0)` will thrown an exception.

Here's a more robust version of your function.

```
void multiply (arr &arr1 ,arr &arr2 )
{
   arr res;

   unsigned num_rows1 = arr1.size();
   if ( num_rows1 == 0 )
   {
      // Can't do much.
      // Return.
      return res;
   }


   unsigned num_cols1 = arr1[0].size();
   if ( num_cols1 == 0 )
   {
      // Can't do much.
      // Return.
      return res;
   }

   // Inner vector size check of arr1.
   for(unsigned int i = 1 ; i < num_rows1 ; i++)
   {
      if ( num_cols1 != arr1[i].size() )
      {
         throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
      }
   }

   // Make sure the number of columns in arr1 is the same as
   // number of rows in arr2.
   unsigned num_rows2 = arr2.size();
   if ( num_cols1 != num_rows2 )
   {
      throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
   }

   unsigned num_cols2 = arr2[0].size();
   if ( num_cols2 == 0 )
   {
      // Can't do much.
      // Return.
      return res;
   }

   // Inner vector size check of arr2.
   for(unsigned int i = 1 ; i < num_rows2 ; i++)
   {
      if ( num_cols2 != arr2[i].size() )
      {
         throw std::runtime_error("Bad input");
      }
   }

   // All inputs appear to be valid.
   // Now, do the multiplication.

   unsigned new_row = num_rows1;
   unsigned new_col = num_cols2;

   res.resize(num_rows1);
   for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < new_row ; i++)
   {
      for(unsigned j = 0 ; j<new_col ;j++)
      {
         int x = 0 ;
         res.at(i).push_back(x);
         for(unsigned k =0 ; k < num_cols1; k++)
         {
            res.at(i).at(j) += arr1.at(i).at(k)*arr2.at(k).at(j);
         }
         cout<< res.at(i).at(j) ;
      }
   }
}
```